# 2.80 grease pencil - highlighted points in edit mode

Tags: grease-pencil

I am testing the new grease pencil and i’ve a little question. In “edit mode” when I select points they’re no more highlighted in orange like before.
Is there something to activate in the interface to see the points highlighted again?

PS: please, excuse my poor english. :p

Comment: I have the same problem  ;)  I have other questions about the 2.8 Grease Pencil, if anyone knows the answer: 1) Is it possible to change the size of the Grease Pencil object symbol, like it's possible to increase an Empty size (without increasing the drawing size)? 2) Is it possible to select and simultaneously move/rotate/scale several pictures of the same animation?

Comment: Instead writing RESOLVED you need to mark answer as correct  https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: so, is blenderstackexchange opened to questions about 2.8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under *Edit Mode* on a Grease Pencil object go to the *Overlays* menu in the *3D View* header and enable *Edit Lines*.

Bellow increase the opacity value as desired. Stroke edges will now appear in a very faint gray color, and selection in orange.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To add to the answer you can do it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> hotkey also.