# Grease Pencil in Blender 2.9 - cannot select vertexes anymore?

Tags: grease-pencil

I have just updated to Blender 2.9 and, when editing a Grease Pencil object, I cannot select individual vertexes [like before](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/118734/14306) anymore, only the whole stroke.
Is there a new option I have to enable ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I found out, it was quite easy...

[image]